# Handlebars render templates based on value

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, handlebars.js

I have the follow data

```
multipleTypes = [
        {"type": "radio", "label": "Cool people names","option": ["Ralgar", "Mozzy"]},
        {"type": "checkbox", "label": "Cool phones", "option": ["android", "iphone"]}
        {"type": "radio", "label": "Cool pets", "option": ["monster", "moose"]},
        {"type": "checkbox", "label": "Cool places", "option": ["bar", "undercovers", "moon"]},
    ]
```

Here are the templates

```
<script id="checkbox-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{label}}</legend>
        {{#each option}}
            <label for="regularCheckbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckbox" value="checkbox 1">
                <span>{{this}}</span>
            </label>
        {{/each}}
    </fieldset>
</script>
<script id="radio-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{label}}</legend>
        {{#each option}}
            <label for="regularRadio">
                <input type="radio" name="radios" id="regularRadio" value="radio 1">
                <span>{{this}}</span>
            </label>
        {{/each}}
    </fieldset>
</script>
```

I'm trying to go down the list of objects and render the template based on the type attribute. Is this possible?

`If else` within the template didn't work out too well.

Comment: The trailing comma in `multipleTypes` will cause you a headache in IE.

Comment: ah, yea i saw and removed that. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars doesn't have a way of testing values, but you could use a helper like [Comparison block helper for handlebars templates](http://doginthehat.com.au/2012/02/comparison-block-helper-for-handlebars-templates/) to test the `type` property and render a particular block of HTML:

```
{{#compare type "radio"}}
Radio HTML
{{/compare}}
{{#compare type "checkbox"}}
Checkbox HTML
{{/compare}}
```

However, you might want to consider transforming your data.  If all inputs are either checkboxes or radios, perhaps use a boolean `radio` property for items that use the radio buttons.  Your data would now look like:

```
multipleTypes = [
    {"radio": true, "label": "Cool people names","option": ["Ralgar", "Mozzy"]},
    {"radio": false, "label": "Cool phones", "option": ["android", "iphone"]}
    {"radio": true, "label": "Cool pets", "option": ["monster", "moose"]},
    {"radio": false, "label": "Cool places", "option": ["bar", "undercovers", "moon"]},
]
```

Then you can use if/else:

```
{{#if radio}}
Radio HTML
{{else}}
Checkbox HTML
{{/if}}
```

Or, just do the template selection in the calling code:

```
var templates = {
  'radio': Handlebars.compile($('#radio-template').html()),
  'checkbox': Handlebars.compile($('checkbox-template').html())
};
multipleTypes.forEach(function(item) {
  var rendered = templates[item.type](item);
  // Do something with rendered output ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('typeRadio', function(obj) {
    return obj.type === 'radio';
});
Handlebars.registerHelper('typeCheckbox', function(obj) {
    return obj.type === 'checkbox';
});
```

Then in your template, use:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>{{label}}</legend>
    {{#if typeRadio}}
        // do radio stuff
    {{/if}}
    {{#if typeCheckbox}}
        // do checkbox stuff
    {{/if}}

</fieldset>
```

Comment: well radio and checkbox was very simplified but each different object will need their own template, it will be an extra 10 or types added. I was wondering if it was a way to look at the each obj, determine the tpl and append one at a time.

Comment: You could do this by loading all the templates into an object and then returning the template text from a helper.

Comment: do you have any links to an example doing so?